# Different values in accessing openCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, floating-point, mat

I'm facing a strange problem.

My Mat is declared as:

`cv::Mat matr(src.rows, src.cols, CV_32FC1);`

If i print it using `cout<<matr` I get all the data in range from 0 to 255 and everything is fine.

If I try to access using this cycle:

```
float* matrF= (float*)matr.data;

for (int r=0; r<matrF.rows; r++)
  {
    for (int c=0; c<matrF.cols; c++)
    {
      std::cout<<matrF[r*matr.cols+c]<<std::endl;
    }
  }
```

I get many values like: `4.684e-42, 2.223e-22` ecc.

If I use

```
for (int r=0; r<matrF.rows; r++)
      {
        for (int c=0; c<matrF.cols; c++)
        {
          std::cout<<matr.data[r*matr.cols+c]<<std::endl;
        }
      }
```

It print some random char and no values.

Ho can I access the element printed using `cout<<matr` ?
I don't want to use function from openCV to access them, I'm trying to loop over the matr.data...

I cant't use `mat.at<float>` or `.step1()`.
Thanks.

---------- SOLUTION

if instead of

```
for (int r=0; r<matrF.rows; r++)
  {
    for (int c=0; c<matrF.cols; c++)
    {
      std::cout<<matrF.data[r*matr.cols+c]<<std::endl;
    }
  }
```

I use

```
for (int r=0; r<matrF.rows; r++)
  {
    for (int c=0; c<matrF.cols; c++)
    {
      float val = matF.data[r*matr.cols+c];
      std::cout<<val<<std::endl;
    }
  }
```

the problem disappears.

Comment: Just found out the problem. Could someone explain that? I edit my post.

Comment: Inszeadt of r*matr.cols use r*matr.step or rowPrt(r) if you want to make it stable for all kind of matrices (which can easily have a padding at the end of each row). .at<float>(row, col) is another fast (in release mode), nice, and well readable way.

Answer (score -1):

It is highly possibly that it is not continuous. Then you cannot use `matr.data` to see all elements.

Please read this tutorial to see what to do: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html

Comment: I want to access data without using functions like `mat.at<float>`

Comment: @0abc0cba0 please look at the tutorial. it tells you how to do it. e.g. get a pointer *row by row*.

Comment: The link does not refer to 32F

Comment: @l000000l Idea is the same. just change `p = I.ptr<uchar>(i);` to `p = I.ptr<float>(i);`. People in stackoverflow should have basic understanding of programming imho.

Comment: I said in the post, I cannot use `.ptr<float>`

Comment: @0abc0cba0 why?

Comment: then just clone your mat, and it will be continous so your method works

Comment: For university project, that function is not allowed

Comment: I solved the problem, look at my post.